# C# Randomizing the ID

Tags: c#, random

I seem to be having trouble with the ID part of my programming. Whenever I run it, it will say that the Student ID is 0. I'm trying to make it where it will call a randomized number between 1000 and 9999. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong and how to go about fixing it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> myList = new List<Student>();


        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.firstName = "John";
        s1.lastName = "Smith";
        s1.sID = 2560;
        myList.Add(s1);

        Student s2 = new Student("Peter ");
        myList.Add(s2);


        Student s3 = new Student("John", "Smith");
        myList.Add(s3);

        Student s4 = new Student("Peter", "Pines");
        myList.Add(s4);


        Student s5 = new Student("Morgan", "Simmons");
        myList.Add(s5);

        Student s6 = new Student("James", "Walters");
        myList.Add(s6);

        Student s7 = new Student("Linda", "Scott", 1005);
        myList.Add(s7);


        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Total students: {0}", Student.Count);            

    }
class Student
{
    private static int count = 0; 
    private string v;
    private int v1;
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }


    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Student(string first, string last)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        count++;
        sID = sID;
        Console.WriteLine("Student Name: {0} {1}; Student ID {3}; count = {2}",
           FirstName, LastName, Count, sID);
    } 
    public Student()
    {
    }

    public Student(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public Student(string first, string last,  int v1) : this(first, last)
    {
        this.v1 = v1;
    }        
    public static int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }
    }
    public static int SID
    {
        get
        {
            return sID;
        }
    }
    public string firstName { get; internal set; }
    public string lastName { get; internal set; }
    public int sID { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. For example, what do you think this is doing? `sID = sID;`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Using `int` for uniqueness isn't very strong but you could use Guid and have `public Guid StudentID {get;internal set;} = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: Is it important that your IDs be completely unique? How often are you calling this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes, 5 times.

Comment: @ShadowSage They *do* have to be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it help if you make a call to yout random number generator

```
public Student(string first, string last)
{
    FirstName = first;
    LastName = last;
    count++;
    sID = rnd.Next(1000, 10000); // to get values between 1000 and 9999
    Console.WriteLine("Student Name: {0} {1}; Student ID {3}; count = {2}",
       FirstName, LastName, Count, sID);
}
```

Anyway, you should pay attention that your ID will not be unique.

Comment: Swapping out the `sID` for `rnd.Next(1000, 9999)`fixed it thank-you so much!

Comment: @ShadowSage It should be `rnd.Next(1000, 10000)` or else you'll never get `9999` as a possible value

Comment: @MatiasCicero OK, I'll be sure to make the change.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of an `int` is 0, with that knowledge take a look at your code again...

You have a Random class instance, but are you using it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I've never worked with randomized numbers before in C# so I don't know how to use that class.

Comment: @ShadowSage Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

As other people have pointed out, you do `sID = sID;` in your constructor instead of calling `Random`.

Just as some general commentary on this approach, if you're interested in the ID actually being unique, see [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339125/acceptable-to-rely-on-random-ints-being-unique) for an explanation of why you can't rely on random numbers to be unique. There are two issues: the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

The Birthday Paradox says that it takes a surprisingly small number of random numbers before there's likely to be a duplicate; in the case of a 32-bit random number, it ends up being about 65K numbers before you're more likely than not to have a duplicate. However, since you're only using 1000 - 9999 (8999 numbers), which is slightly more than 2^13.135, the birthday paradox states that it would take approximately sqrt(2^13.135) (approximately 95) numbers before it's just as likely as not that there's a duplicate - again, a surprisingly small number.

At `2^32 + 1` numbers generated, there [**must** be *at least* one duplicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) for a 32-bit number. For the values 1000 - 9999, you must have at least one duplicate once you reach 9,000 numbers generated.

The Gambler's Fallacy refers to the (mistaken) belief that independent events somehow influence each other. For example, if you generate a `5` on one particular call to `Random`, you're somehow less likely to generate a `5` on the next call. This isn't true - you're actually *just as likely* to generate another 5 on the next call as you were on the call that actually resulted in a 5.

In practice, if you're only doing 5 calls and the ID only needs to be unique for that particular "run" of the application, the actual probability of generating duplicates for 5 random numbers is relatively low (but not impossible). If you need the ID to be unique across application "runs" and/or you start calling this more often, this could become very problematic very quickly though.

Comment: I love the commentary on probability - for the vast majority of people, these concepts are unable to be learned.

Answer (score 1):

As @maccettura pointed out you are not assigning a value to the `sId` of the `Student` class.

If you want to ensure that the ID's are really unique (although random the same number can be generated multiple times) you might consider to change from `int` to `string` and use the Guid generator of the .net Framework. E.g.

```
 string sId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

This produces strings like `0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e`

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you assign the ID to itself (`sID = sID;`)

You should use your `Random`-object like this:

```
sID = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);
```